# Is it possible to add custom "napkin math" operators in OneNote 2007?

Tags: math, plugins, office-2007, onenote

If you're not familiar with OneNote's "[napkin math](http://blogs.msdn.com/onenotetips/archive/2008/05/09/napkin-math-in-onenote.aspx)" feature, it allows you to type mathematical equations and have OneNote evaluate them on the fly (with a limited set of operators/functions). I'm wondering if it's possible to create my own, either through an obscure UI in OneNote, or through some sort of custom plugin that I would develop.

Just wondering. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer, but might provide helpful.

Interesting question, my first thought is to create an add-in. You can use *Visual Studio* and C#/VB.NET. I have written an add-in and it is just like the COM Add-in, since it is not a VSTO application. OneNotes object model is different.

I have been meaning to check out *OneNote Object Model*

> ***OneNote Object Model***
>
> A managed code
>   wrapper for the extensibility API for
>   Microsoft Office OneNote 2007. Allows
>   users to use an object model to
>   interact with the OneNote store.
>
> Inserted from
>   http://onom.codeplex.com/